# Using ember data to save multiple records via post

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Does anyone know of any working examples of overriding ember-data's DS.Adapter to save all records at once?

I'd like to stringify my entire array of records and send them to my server.  I don't have much flexibility on the server to use anything but the existing API which is just a perl CGI script.  Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: perl CGI? this is probably the only app using Ember and perl cgi I would think

Comment: i'm the world's first. wooohoo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did was iterate over the ember-data models, serialized them, saved them into a json object that matched server requirements, and executed post request.

```
var identifiedResponse = []
this.store.filter(key, function (record) {
   return !!record.get('name')
}).then(function(resp) {
    identifiedResponse.push(item.serialize())
    })
jQuery.ajax({
       url: url,
       type: "POST",
       data: identifiedResponse,
       contentType: "application/json",
       dataType: 'json',
       xhrFields: {
       withCredentials: true
       }
 })
```

Comment: I tried similar, I can't remember what went wrong for me trying this.  I'll give it a go. Thanks for the response.